# CSS Inner Box Shadow for IE 7 and 8

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have an inner box shadow sort of working with this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow (OffX='-2', OffY='0', Color='#e2e3e7')
```

But it makes more of a solid line inside the div... not a gradient shadow. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Hack:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=-2, OffY=0, Color='#e2e3e7')
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2)
```